# WSO2 API config, query param to payload factory to json to data service

Tags: wso2

I'm having a few problems in understanding how to pass a query param to a payload factory that creates a json, and then passing its data to a data service.
What I thought would be the correct config is

```js
<payloadFactory media-type="json">
    <format>{"cod_uo" : "$1"}</format>
    <args>
        <arg evaluator="xml" expression="get-property('query.param.id')"/>
    </args>
</payloadFactory>
<log>
    <property expression="json-eval($.cod_uo)" name="string"/>
</log>
<dataServiceCall description="GET operation" serviceName="MyService">
    <operations type="single">
        <operation name="MyOperationName">
            ---> <param evaluator="xml" expression="json-eval('$.cod_uo')" name="cod_uo"/> <-- This Line
        </operation>
    </operations>
    <source type="inline"/>
    <target type="body"/>
</dataServiceCall>
```

but the system doesn't recognize the json-eval function here.
I tried also a direct json evaluation with

```
<param evaluator="json" name="id" expression="$.cod_uo"/>
```

but i get a DataServiceCallMediator

```
Current Request Name: MyOperationName
Current Params: {cod_uo=}
Nested Exception:-
java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: ""
```

What is the correct method to use the 'cod_uo' property of the payload factory payload in a subsequent data service call?

---

I'm using the latest Integration Studio (8.0.0.202104161647)

The log ALWAYS returns

```
{api:MyApi:v1.0.0} To: /my/path?id=123, MessageID: urn:uuid:[uuid], correlation_id: [correlation_id], Direction: request, string = 123
```

All combinations + errors:

```js
<param evaluator="xml" expression="json-eval('$.cod_uo')" name="cod_uo"/>

[2021-07-30 08:50:41,179] ERROR {SynapseXPath} - Evaluation of the XPath expression json-eval('$.cod_uo') resulted in an error org.jaxen.UnresolvableException: No Such Function json-eval
```

```js
<param evaluator="xml" expression="json-eval($.cod_uo)" name="cod_uo"/>

(doesn't compile: "Invalid XPath expression for attribute expression : json-eval($.cod_uo)"
```

```js
<param evaluator="json" expression="json-eval('$.cod_uo')" name="cod_uo"/>
<param evaluator="json" expression="json-eval($.cod_uo)" name="cod_uo"/>
<param evaluator="json" expression="$.cod_uo" name="cod_uo"/>


Current Request Name: MyOperationName
Current Params: {cod_uo=}
Nested Exception:-
org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: invalid input syntax for integer: ""
```

```js
<param evaluator="xml" expression="$.cod_uo" name="cod_uo"/>

(doesn't compile: Invalid XPath expression for attribute expression : $.cod_uo)
```

Comment: Are both the `Payload Factory` mediator and `DataServiceCall` mediator in the same sequence? Or you are having different services and trying to access the JSON payload from another sequence? If you are using the same sequence, we can use `get-property('query.param.id')` instead of the `json-eval` expression to fulfill your requirement. Do you have any specific requirements to access the property using the `json-eval`?

Comment: They are both in the same sequence (payload factory -> dss).
I know I could use the get-property, but i'm trying to fetch the modified payload.
I don't *need* to use json-eval, but I thought it was the right function to use to fetch a json sub-object

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since both `Payload Factory` mediator and the `Data Service Call` mediator is in the same sequence, you can make use of the `get-property()` function to retrieve the value and assign it.

For example,

```xml
<param evaluator="json" name="id" expression="get-property('query.param.id')"/>
```

Furthermore, if you wanted to access the property through `json-eval()`, I think there has been a typo that is causing the empty value behavior. Please remove the quotes around the key and try the scenario

> **Update Note**: The `json-eval()` approach didn't solve the problem. But, keeping the following segment as a reference. Look at the `Update` section to access the payload using XPath expression.

```xml
<!-- without single quotes around the $.myId -->
<param evaluator="json" name="id" expression="json-eval($.myId)"/>
```

---

#### Update

You can also try accessing the Payload using XPath expression as following

```xml
<param evaluator="xml" name="id" expression="$body//myId"/>
```

Comment: The error says that the function is not recognized; moreover, without the quotes the sequence doesn't even seem valid

Comment: Could you share which EI version you are using? Also, can you attach the errors that you are observing?

Comment: Sure, I just added all the infos.

Comment: @Mewster, it seems the `DataServiceCall` mediator only supports XML evaluators and XPaths not JSON. Therefore, you may have to go with the `get-property()` or else, you can try accessing the payload using `$body//myId` and verify.

Comment: Using $body//myId was the solution. Thanks

Comment: ( I'd suggest to edit away the json-eval('') because it's not supported